# FFMPEG - Accurately cutting video/audio and merging multiple videos together

Tags: ffmpeg

**This post has been updated since the original post**

thanks in advance for any help I get with this...

I am working with 4 video assets....all stereo audio, same a/v spec.

intro -
mainvideo -
midroll_video (advert) -
endboard

I need to add an audio **only** cross fade between the 2 video elements **part2.mp4** and **pip.mp4**. These 2 videos are made by the code (rather than being 2 of the 4 videos listed above). I have added in the code as kindly instructed by @Баяр Гончикжапов but unfortunately it is still not working. See conversation below for more info/ the part i need help with.

Thanks in advance!

This is the code I am using.

````
# Input parameters
mainvideo=mezzfile.mp4
endboard=endboard.mp4
intro=sting.mp4
midroll_video=midroll.mp4

tailtime=20
fadelength=0.2
midroll_edit_value=00:11:31.600

# Time calculations to define cut point
duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $mainvideo)
endboard_cut_point=$(echo "scale=2;$duration-$tailtime" | bc)

duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $mainvideo)
midroll_cut_point=$(echo "scale=2;$duration-$midroll_edit_value" | bc)

# Safety check
tbn_main=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=time_base -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $mainvideo)
tbn_main=${tbn_main#*/}
tbn_intro=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=time_base -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $intro)
tbn_intro=${tbn_intro#*/}
tbn_end=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=time_base -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $endboard)
tbn_end=${tbn_end#*/}

if [[ $(( ($tbn_intro+$tbn_main+$tbn_end)/3 )) -ne $tbn_main ]]; then
  echo "WARNING: source video files have the different timebase."
  echo "The use of the concat demuxer will produce incorrect output."
  echo "Re-encoding is highly recommended."
  read -s -k $'?Press any key to exit.\n'
  exit 1
fi

# Trim the main part of mainvideo
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $mainvideo -to $midroll_edit_value -c copy part1.mp4

ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $mainvideo -ss $midroll_edit_value -to $endboard_cut_point -c copy part2.mp4

ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $mainvideo -ss $midroll_edit_value -to $duration -c copy part2av.mp4


# Trim the tail of mainvideo and overlay it onto endboard
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -i $mainvideo \
  -i $endboard \
  -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]select='gt(t,$duration-$tailtime)',scale=w=iw/2.03:h=ih/2.03,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v_tail]; \
     [0:a]aselect='gt(t,$duration-$tailtime)',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a_out]; \
     [1:v][v_tail]overlay=format=auto[v_out]" \
  -map "[v_out]" \
  -map "[a_out]" \
  -video_track_timescale $tbn_main \
  pip.mp4

ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i "part2.mp4" -i "part2av.mp4" -i "pip.mp4" \
  -filter_complex \
     -map "[0:v];" 
     -map "[1:a];" 
     -map "[2:v]" 
     -c copy "part2pip.mp4" \

# Pass all parts through the concat demuxer
[ -f filelist.txt ] && rm filelist.txt
for f in $intro part1.mp4 $midroll_video part2pip.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'" >> filelist.txt; done
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -c copy TEST_FILE.mp4

# Sweep the table
rm pip.mp4 part1.mp4 part2.mp4 filelist.txt```
````

Comment: if use segments to split `-c copy -f segment -segment_times 3:62 %d.mp4` it will cut on nearest keyframe

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tested your idea and it worked great in isolation. It cut the main video at the time I gave it and created to new video files containing each segment. However, when I add it into my main code, it does not quite work as expect.

Comment: Although all of the video assets are exactly the same spec, for some reason the file that the code outputs is reading at a frame rate of 24.903fps (?!) even though all the files are 25fps. 

The log of the code flags numerous times the following....
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 699197, current: 698850; changing to 699198. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

....And when playing back the output file, it seems to freeze at the segment cut point and then when it does start playing back the video is playing back faster than the audio.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening and any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thank you again for your help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to add `... 3:62 -reset_timestamps 1 %d.mp4`

Comment: Unfortunately, that gave me the same result. Lots of **[mp4 @ 0x108f110f0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 725222, current: 724962; changing to 725223. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file** errors and again, the file is not playing back properly. It freezes at the cut point and then plays back the video really fast, while the audio plays back normally.

Comment: try to concat not all files at once, do it step by step: $intro and 0.mp4, then 0.mp4 with $midroll_video, etc. to calculate which connection is faulty. then compare them to find what is difference between them

Comment: I have slightly changed the code above and it is now not overlapping as much, which at this stage would be ok as its just 2/3 frames.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов The only thing I need to figure out now is how to feed the code a specific timecode or number of frames and have the video cut at that exact point. 

Is there a way to do this in HH:MM:SS:MSS or frame number and actually have it cut at that point rather than roughly at that point?

What would need to be changed in the code to implement this?

Many thanks for all your help. Greatly appreciated

Comment: You are fighting with keyframes. You can split $mainvideo to 3 segments at 750+-5 sec. Reencode mid part inserting $midroll_video at exact point.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have attempted what you suggested, but unfortunately, the cut at -5 and +5 are not accurate. The video side of things seems to be ok, but the audio has just over a frame of silent audio before the cut. 

Do you know why this would be and is there a way to make the audio not contain this silent frame?

Thank you very much for your help @БаярГончикжапов :D

Comment: I have my time references set like this...

    **midroll_pre=00:12:12.250
midroll_post=00:12:35.125**

and then the code that references them like this...

    **# Trim the main part of mainvideo
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i $mainvideo -to $midroll_pre -c:v copy -c:a aac part1.mp4**

Comment: split using `-segment_times $(($midroll_edit_value-5)),$(($midroll_edit_value+5))` or `-segment_times 12:25,12:45` then get duration of `0.mp4` calculate position in `1.mp4`: `(( m=$midroll_edit_value-$dura_of_0mp4 ))` and insert $midroll_video at this position ising trim,atrim: `[0:v]trim=0:$m[v0];[0:v]trim=$m[v1];[v0][1:v][v1]concat...`

Comment: Thank you for your help @БаярГончикжапов . Apologies, I'm really new to all this and I'm not totally sure how to write this section of the code in full. Would you be able to write this section in full for me to insert into the main code? I attempted it, but it is not right.

Comment: I understand the logic behind splitting the mainvideo into segments based on the -/+5 but I am confused by the rest of what you suggested. I would massively appreciate your help with getting this sorted. 

I have updated the code in the original post to reflect where I am at, at the moment. Initially, the edit at midroll_pre would cut the video perfectly, but for some reason would add 1/2 frames of silence before the cut point in the audio. 

I need to get rid of these 1/2 frames of silence in the audio and would massively appreciate your help to of this @БаярГончикжапов

Answer (score 0):

Insert video in the middle of main video and use -f concat:

```
# Input parameters.
# All video has same properties: codec_name, width, height, sample_aspect_ratio, r_frame_rate, time_base, pix_fmt
# if one of the video has difference then this video needs to be transcoded
# All audio has same properties: codec_name, channels, sample_rate
# if audio has diff: aresample=async=1,apad,atrim=0:$duration -ac 2
# get durations of audio and video and container: ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries format=duration:stream=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f"
intro=VID_20230206_113828.mp4
mainvideo=VID_20230206_113949.mp4
endboard=VID_20230206_114456.mp4
midroll_video=VID_20230206_114248.mp4

#tailtime=20
tailtime=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$endboard")
midroll_edit_value=25

#WID=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$mainvideo")
#HEI=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$mainvideo")
#SAR=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=sample_aspect_ratio -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$mainvideo")
#if [ "$SAR" = "N/A" ]; then SAR=1; fi
FPS=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$mainvideo")
TBN=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=time_base -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$mainvideo")
TBN=${TBN#*/}
#FMT=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=pix_fmt -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$mainvideo")
echo $WID $HEI $SAR $FPS $TBN $FMT
#CHL=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=channel_layout -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$main")
#SRA=$(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$main")
#echo $CHL $SRA

# Trim the main part of mainvideo
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i "$mainvideo" -c copy \
-f segment -segment_times $(($midroll_edit_value-5)),$(($midroll_edit_value+5)) \
-reset_timestamps 1 %d.mp4

# Insert mid
dura_0mp4=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 0.mp4)
m=$( echo "$midroll_edit_value - $dura_0mp4" | bc -l )
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i 1.mp4 -i $midroll_video -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=0:${m}[v0];
[0:v]trim=${m},setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
[0:a]atrim=0:${m}[a0];
[0:a]atrim=${m},asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
[v0][a0][1:v][1:a][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" \
-r $FPS \
-video_track_timescale $TBN \
1_mid.mp4

# Time calculations to define cut point
dura_2mp4=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 2.mp4)
endboard_cut_point=$(echo "$dura_2mp4-$tailtime" | bc -l)
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i 2.mp4 -t $endboard_cut_point -c copy part2.mp4

# Trim the tail of mainvideo and overlay it onto endboard
echo "" > fcs.txt
PAD="[1:v]"
NUM=25
SCA=$((3*$NUM))
for (( i=0; i<$NUM; i++ )); do
  echo "[0:v]trim=start_frame=$i:end_frame=$(($i+1)),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+$i*N,scale=iw-iw*$i/$SCA:ih-ih*$i/$SCA[f$i];" >> fcs.txt
  echo "$PAD[f$i]overlay=enable='eq(n,$i)'[o$i];" >> fcs.txt
  PAD="[o$i]"
done
echo "[0:v]trim=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1/TB,scale=iw-iw*$i/$SCA:ih-ih*$i/$SCA[f$i];" >> fcs.txt
echo "$PAD[f$i]overlay=enable='gte(t,1)'" >> fcs.txt
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
-ss $endboard_cut_point -i 2.mp4 \
-i $endboard \
-filter_complex_script fcs.txt \
-r $FPS \
-video_track_timescale $TBN \
pip.mp4

# Pass all parts through the concat demuxer
[ -f filelist.txt ] && rm filelist.txt
for f in $intro 0.mp4 1_mid.mp4 part2.mp4 pip.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'" >> filelist.txt; done
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -c copy TEST_FILE.mp4

mpv TEST_FILE.mp4
```

If you cut video by this code and check:

```
ffmpeg -i $mainvideo -ss 30 -c copy part2.mp4
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,flags \
-of csv=print_section=0 "part2.mp4"  | awk -F',' '/K/ {print $1}'
```

you can see something like this `start:0.016000` and keyframes didn't starts from 0.000000, starts from 2.266016, for example. Because first keyframe is before beginning. If you concat that file without encoding you can get desync.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251741/discussion-on-answer-by---ffmpeg-accurately-cutting-video-audio); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.